# Windows Server 2012 r2 stuck at spinning logo after cold boot

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

Specs :

1. X99 taichi
2. Intel xeon 12 core E2670 V3 ES
3. Corsair 8x4 Gb ram 2133 mhz
4. ssd Kingston SUV400S37120G

The Pcie has several peripherals :

- LSI 9300-8e for connecting to a JBOD rack. 
  it's an avago based card. But during boot this card only takes about 3 secs to load its config.
- Nvidia Geforce Gt 730, cause x99 chipset doesnt have internal display.
- Intel nic 1g for connecting to a POE switch

Issue : 
After cold boot, i.e turning off and turn on the server, the boot process is always stuck at spinning white dots. 
Strangely after force-rebooting it, it always boots fine afterwards. 
This annoys me because when blackout occurs, i will have to go to the machine to manually force reboot it. And im also worried about force rebooting it too often,

I have replaced :

1. memory
2. CPU, it used to be not detected and now its detected as Xeon e5 v2670 ES
3. SAS card from LSI 9300-8e to another 9300-8e, but it didn't make a difference, still stuck, so i install the old one again

How do i trace down the cause of this in event log?

Comment: Enable boot logging. Then review the log file.

Comment: thanks, just did it. it's a 24/7 server so i will wait tommorow morning until it's low traffic

Comment: Eh.. forget something, what if i want to do this AFTER shutdown state instead of reboot state? would it work as well? because the issue seems to happen after cold boot

Comment: If it happens on a cold boot then enable boot logging, shut down the server, then cold boot it.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/UFb7AXdz, sorry i could shut it down today, it stuck again on  spinning logo